# Почему в результате группового запроса объединяются одинаковые значения

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50),country_id INT );
CREATE TABLE companies (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50),city_id INT ,labors INT );

INSERT INTO cities (name, country_id) VALUES ('Boston', 2),
                                         ('Moscow', 1),
                                         ('Lipetsk', 1),
                                         ('Berlin', 4),
                                         ('Frankfurt', 4),
                                         ('London', 3);

INSERT INTO companies (name, city_id, labors) VALUES ('Google', 1, 3000),
                                                 ('Yandex', 2, 2000),
                                                 ('Bosh', 4, 1100),
                                                 ('Stern', 5, 500),
                                                 ('Energoprom', 3, 400),
                                                 ('Lipton', 6, 500),
                                                 ('X5', 2, 1500);
```

И два запроса:

```
SELECT city_id FROM companies WHERE labors > 1000;

SELECT name, country_id FROM cities WHERE cities.id IN (SELECT city_id FROM companies WHERE labors > 1000);
```

Результаты запросов:

| city_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 2 |

| name | country_id |
| --- | --- |
| Boston | 2 |
| Moscow | 1 |
| Berlin | 4 |

Почему во втором результате выводятся только 3 города? Почему не повторяется Moscow?Как сделать чтобы повторялась?

Comment: *Как сделать чтобы повторялась?* Заменить WHERE IN на INNER JOIN. *Почему во втором результате выводятся только 3 города?* Сколько бы раз Москва не значилась в некоем списке - второй Москвы от этого не построится...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал тут JOIN

```
SELECT cities.name, cities.country_id
FROM cities INNER JOIN companies ON cities.id = companies.city_id
WHERE companies.labors > 1000
```

А вообще немного запутанные таблицы, непонятные id

Comment: Спасибо за ответ